# SQL: Changing datetime into seconds

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I had a calculation in my query to minus one datetime from another which has given me the correct result in terms of it's given to me in minutes and seconds but it is displaying oddly and I want to change it to just show seconds. I'll show you the section of code and the result below:

SELECT *, (last_hit - first_hit) as hit_difference,

FROM (SELECT
id,
MIN(case when pagepath LIKE '%yourquote%' THEN hittime end) AS first_hit,
MAX(case when pagepath LIKE '%yourquote%' THEN hittime end) AS last_hit

first_hit *example* 2022-01-11 16:59:22.770 UTC
last_hit *example* 2022-01-11 17:01:08.964 UTC
hit_difference ***result*** 0-0 0 0:1:46.194

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change it to just show seconds.

Use below instead

```
SELECT *, 
  (UNIX_SECONDS(last_hit) - UNIX_SECONDS(first_hit)) as hit_difference,
FROM ...
```